# Elasticsearch 6.2 - Query string issue with and without whitespace in query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a problem about my ELASTICSEARCH 6.2 query.

```
{ "query_string" : { "default_field": "movie_title",  "default_operator": "AND", "analyze_wildcard":true, "query": "spiderman" } }
```

In my documents, i have 2 records, with two differents title: "Spider man", and "Spiderman"

For a search with "spider man", i have all documents, but with "spiderman", i have only 1 result (and he don't find 'spider man').

I have try a lot of tokenizer, analyzer but anything was good. How is possible to fix this problem ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with SHINGLE Filter !

```
"analysis": {


          "filter": {
                "shingle_filter": {
                    "type":"shingle",
                       "max_shingle_size":5,
                       "min_shingle_size":2,
                       "output_unigrams":"true",
                       "token_separator": ""
                }
            },


          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {

              "type":      "custom",
              "tokenizer": "lowercase",
              "filter":    ["shingle_filter"]

            }
          }


    }
```